Dependent random variables whose convolution adds up
I want to find two dependent random variables $X$ and $Y$ with values in $\mathbb{Z}$ such that $P_X\star P_Y=P_{X+Y}$, where $\star$ is the convolution.
What I've tried:
I was "tickling" with several Dirac measures but that seems unsuitable because the propabilities taken are only zero and one and the variables tend to become independent in case the convolution adds up, e.g.:

Suppose that $P$ is defined on $\mathbb{Z}$ equals $\delta_x$ for some $x\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $X=\mathrm{id}$ and $Y=X$. Then, $P_X=P_Y=\delta_x$ and $P_X\star P_Y=\delta_{2x}=P_{X+Y}$, but the variable is independent of itself. Or otherwise, as above, but $Y=X+1$, then $P_X=\delta_x$, $P_Y=\delta_{x+1}$ and $P_{X}\star P_{Y}=\delta_{2x+1}=P_{X+Y}$ but, again, the variables $X$ and $Y$, although they don't look like it, are independent.

Suppose that $P$ is defined on $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$ equals $\frac{1}{2}\delta_{(0,1)}+\frac{1}{2}\delta_{(0,2)}$ and $X=\mathrm{pr}_1$ and $Y=\mathrm{pr}_1+\mathrm{pr}_2$. Then, $P_X=\delta_0$, $P_Y=\frac{1}{2}\delta_1+\frac{1}{2}\delta_2$ and $P_X\star P_Y=P_Y=P_{X+Y}$, but, again, the variables are independent.



This had been answered here, probably, more than once. I'll try to find.

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4507999/find-two-dependent-random-variables-x-and-y-such-that-phi-xyt-phi-x

Sorry, I googled but didn't find anything. Sorry , for the duplicate

The first link speaks about the Cauchy distribution which is not defined on $\mathbb{Z}$

For the second link, I don't see the relation to my question. If you can elaborate, I would be happy

Oops, sorry, it's Z, didn't pay attention. Pretty sure it's answered too. I'll search.

It should be doable much more simple without extra concepts
